# How to create temporary table and dynamic field by row table?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create temp table on MS-SQL but create filed by other row data

Table X

```
FieldA 
=======
SkillA
SkillB
SkillC
```

Temp Table

```
SkillA     SkillB    SkillC
============================
Null         Null       Null
```

Thank you for help

I want to execute on server side. And I don't know amount row data.
I expand.

```
TABLE X
FieldA    FieldB
===================
 SKillA    SubjectA
 SkillB    SubjectB
 SkillC    SubjectC
...
...
*** I don't know amount row data ***

Temp Table
SkillA   SubjectA   SkillB   SubjectB  SkillC  SubjectC
========================================================
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you want to do. With a practical example maybe.

Comment: Use PIVOT http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #temp

DECLARE @temp TABLE (FieldA NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @temp (FieldA)
VALUES 
    ('SkillA'),
    ('SkillB'),
    ('SkillC')

SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM (
    SELECT FieldA, a = CAST(NULL AS INT) 
    FROM @temp
) src
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(a) 
    FOR FieldA IN (SkillA, SkillB, SkillC)
) unpvt

SELECT * 
FROM #temp t
```

**Output:**

```
SkillA      SkillB      SkillC
----------- ----------- -----------
NULL        NULL        NULL
```

***Update 2:*** I don't know amount row data

**Query:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.##temp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE ##temp

DECLARE @temp TABLE (FieldA VARCHAR(20), FieldB VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @temp (FieldA, FieldB)
VALUES 
    ('SKillA', 'SubjectA'),
    ('SkillB', 'SubjectB'),
    ('SkillC', 'SubjectC')

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = '
    SELECT * 
    INTO ##temp 
    FROM (
    SELECT ' + STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ', [' + FieldA + '] = NULL, [' + FieldB + '] = NULL'
    FROM @temp
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ') t 
    WHERE 1 != 1'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT * 
FROM ##temp t
```

**Output:**

```
SKillA      SubjectA    SkillB      SubjectB    SkillC      SubjectC
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
```

Comment: but this way you still have to know your rows right? and what if we dont know how many "skill N" we want to create?